# Norm of Linear operator as a limit

Tags: operator-theory, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

It is known that a linear operator on Banach space not necessarily attains its norm (meaning that there is no element $x$ s.t. $\|Tx\| = \|T\|$). I would like to clarify that there is a sequence that tends to the norm.

Let $X$, $Y$ be two Banach spaces, and $T:X\to Y$ be a bounded operator. Is it true, that there is a sequence $\{x_i\}\subset X$ s.t. $\|T\| = \lim_{i\to\infty}\|Tx_i\|_Y$?

Comment: Easy to prove: if $T\neq 0$, then $\lVert T(X)\rVert_Y=[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$||T||= \sup \{||Tx||_Y: x \in X , ||x||_X=1\}.$$

Foe  each $n \in \mathbb N$, there is $x_n \in X$ such that $||x_n||=1$ and $||Tx_n||_Y > ||T||-\frac{1}{n}.$

Thus

$$||T||-\frac{1}{n} <||Tx_n||_Y \le ||T|| \cdot ||x_n||_X =||T||$$

for all $n$. Then we get, with $ n \to \infty:$

$$||Tx_n||_Y  \to ||T||.$$

Remark: it suffices that $X$ and $Y$ are normed spaces.

Comment: Nice point not to invoke completeness of $Y$!

Answer (score 1):

The operator norm is $$||T||= \sup_{||x|| \le 1, x \in X}||Tx||$$ Now, since $T$ is bounded, then $||T||= \sup_{||x|| \le 1, x \in X}||Tx|| < \infty$

By completeness of the space $Y$, we can always take a maximizing sequence: a sequence $(x_i)_i \in X^{\mathbb{N}}$ s.t. $\|T\| = \lim_{i\to\infty}\|Tx_i\|_Y$, that is, we take a sequence converging to the least upper bound.

***Note***: you are not using properties of the real numbers since the operator has values in $Y$, but still, $Y$ is a Banach space and so by completeness you can get the desired result.